# Matrix Rotation Questions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

1. Find the matrix $A$ for a counterclockwise rotation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ taking the line $4x-3y=0$ to the $y$-axis.
2. Find the matrix $C$ for the clockwise rotation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ taking the $y$-axis to the line $4x-3y=0$.

I've done rotations using the standard rotation matrix, but I'm not sure what the question means when it says "taking the line to the $y$-axis." 
I also got that the angle for the first one should be $37$ degrees, but it doesn't seem to be right. Thanks

Comment: For 1) it means, can you find the angle between the line and the positive y-axis? This is the angle of rotation you need. (Why wouldnt 37 degrees be correct? What did you do?) Any point on the line subject to this angle of rotation, will end up on the y-axis. The angle here isn't "exact" so you do need to round...

Comment: So it would be: \begin{bmatrix}cos(37)&sin(37)\\sin(37)&cos(37)\end{bmatrix} with top right sin being negative? Because I'm told this is wrong

Comment: Actually, the values in the rotation matrix (that you need to find in this problem) can be very found in a very exact form. (And that's kinda the reason the angle isn't exact.)

Comment: How would I find the exact form? i don't think I'm understanding this question.

Comment: in the previous version of the question that you just deleted, i had added that into my answer

Comment: your answer is also right, but don't forget to convert properly between radians and degrees.  The trigonometric functions take arguments in radians, not degrees. $37$ degrees is about $37 * 2\pi / 360$ radians, or better yet, $\theta = \sin^{-1}(3/5)$.  You can evaluate $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ explicitly

Comment: My bad, I didn't mean to delete the last one. So, I would just need to convert to radians? Because my answer is still not being accepted, I don't know if I'm rounding wrong or something.

Comment: Yes, you just need to convert the angle in degrees to radians.  But there's no need to round.  How did you get the angle? Presumably from $\theta = \sin^{-1}(3/5) = \cos^{-1}(4/5)$, by looking at a right triangle formed by the y-axis and the line $y = 4x/3$.  Using that, you can express the entries of the rotation matrix as clean fractions.

Comment: I'm still slightly confused as to how you're not rounding. Wouldn't the angle not be exact?

Comment: I'm not rounding because $\sin(\sin^{-1}(x)) = x$, and $\cos(\cos^{-1}(x)) = x$.  If $\theta = \sin^{-1}(3/5)$, then $\sin(\theta) = 3/5$.

Comment: You don’t need the exact rotation angle to build these matrices, you just need its sine and cosine, which you can extract from the slope of the line.